# Get list of calendar resources in Android app?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

I am writing an Android app that needs to get the scheduled events for a calendar resource in Google Calendar (in my case a conference room). Most examples I've found online deal with the REST API, Oath, etc. from an external application (lots of PHP, JS, Python questions), but I am going to be using a standard Android app. Are there built-in Java classes for this as part of Google Apps/Google Play Services? It's acceptable to require the device to be signed into a Google account and that account to have the relevant resources added to "my calendars".

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this link -  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/android ? Sample apps are also available - https://github.com/miguelarauj1o/GoogleCalendarQuickStart

Comment: Thanks, I am trying that but I am getting the "403 - Access not configured" response. I have enabled the Calendar API and put the correct SHA1 fingerprint for it, so I am confused.

Comment: Did you try the solution mentioned at the end of the documentation page ?

Comment: Did I make sure that the package and SHA1 match? Yes.

Comment: Did you add your email address to the OAuth consent tab ?

Comment: Yep, it's there, and it's the one I choose in the sample app copied from Google.

Comment: Fixed it - the Gradle file had the incorrect package, while the manifest was correct. Thanks!